# Javascript unit tesing, test hitting a callback inside function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon, chai

I am having trouble getting complete coverage in my testing where I am trying to hit a callback function inside the function I am testing. Here is the function :

```
CrowdControl.prototype.get = function() {
    var options = this.optionsFor('GET');
    return q.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        function callback(error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve(body);
            }
        }

        request(options, callback);
    });
};
```

So I have the function covered off except the function callback :

```
function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
        reject(error);
    } else {
        resolve(body);
    }
}
```

I cant seem to figure out how to hit this with tests.

Up top I have the request stubbed out like this

```
   var request = sinon.stub();

beforeEach(function() {
    CrowdControl = rewire('crowdcontrol');
    CrowdControl.__set__({
        request: request
    });
});
```

So I'm not sure how I can make it hit the callback and test that. Could use some insight as this is still new to me. Thanks!

So I'm trying a simple test at first something like this -

```
 it("should call callback function.", function() {
        crowdControl.get();
        //callback should fire?
        expect(callback).to.have.been.called;

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way to achieve what you want is this:

```
CrowdControl.prototype.get = function(callback) {
    callback = callback || function callback(error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve(body);
            }
        };
    var options = this.optionsFor('GET');
    return q.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        callback();
        request(options, callback);
    });
};
```

You can now inject the function in when testing (it will use the real implementation if the argument is not supplied).

```
CrowdControl.get(someFakeFunction);
```

Comment: I'd prefer not to organize the function (as I did not create it, I am just writing tests for it) if possible

Comment: Well in many cases you have to do some refactor if you really need to cover each line

Comment: Another way might be to redefine q.Promise(...)

Comment: Just a quick follow up - jshint is yelling at me for this  W117  Line 72, Col 17  'reject' is not defined.
 W117  Line 74, Col 17  'resolve' is not defined.
 W098  Line 78, Col 40  'reject' is defined but never used.
 W098  Line 78, Col 31  'resolve' is defined but never used.

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with functions that return promise, you have to make your asserts (expect) are inside then(), so it will look something like this:

```
    it("should call callback function.", function(done) {
var callback = sinon.stub();           
 crowdControl.get(callback).then(function(){
       expect(callback).to.have.been.called;
       done();
    });
```

Comment: So, where would callback be defined here to stub? Or rather - how is the callback stubbed in this instance?

Comment: I think the best way is to define your callback outside as in @garryp answer, and then have callback = sinon.stub() in your beaforeEach() and pass it to crowdControl.get(callback)